# Can an MySQL query execute something like flow-control?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with duplicate entries:

```
|User|Product|
--------------
|John| apple |
|John| orange|
|Tim | apple |
|Tom | grape |
|Kath| orange|
```

I want to select User's who have orange, but I want to eliminate Users that are entered more than once. I usually think in code, so my reference is an if statement, but is there an easy way to do this within the query. Here's the logic in pseudocode:

```
foreach row
  if Product = orange
    if User not in userList && not in duplicateList
      userList += row.User // add User to the userList
    else if User in userList
      remove User from userList
      duplicateList += row.User
```

Please advise if I can improve the question title as well.

Comment: Based on this input provide desired output. Also provide logic behind why you want to eliminate John and do not want to eliminate Kath.

Comment: Look like XY Problem

Comment: @lad2025 definitely could be, I don't usually build queries and I could definitely be using the wrong tool, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
try this:

```
SELECT Tab.`User`
FROM Tab
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `User`, COUNT(Product)
            FROM Tab
            GROUP BY `User`
            HAVING COUNT(Product) > 1) AS Tab2
ON Tab.`User` = Tab2.`User`
WHERE Product LIKE "Orange"
AND Tab2.`User` IS NULL
```

Comment: I quote `user` because it is keyword

Comment: Thanks @MattiaCaputo that's what I was looking for. Now I just have to join with another table...